# When instantiating lua class with methods does the methods slow down the programs performance.?

Tags: performance, class, methods, lua, lua-table

When creating lua class with methods and then instantiating it will the
methods slow down the table or program? example below?

```
local Person= {}

Person.name = ""
Person.age = 0

function Person:new(person)
   local newPerson = person or {}
   setmetatable(newPerson,self)
   self.__index = self
   return newPerson
end

function Person:giveName()
   self.name = "John"
end

return Person
```

In another file

```
local Person = require(location.Person)
local allPeople = {}

for i = 1,1000 do
   local newPerson = Person:new()
   allPeople[i] = newPerson
end
```

Does the methods get added to the table and does it make the performance
less of the table or program?

Comment: Have you measured the performance?

Comment: Hello No but that is good idea I will look into that.

Comment: Here's a list of lua [profilers](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ProfilingLuaCode) that will help you do what @lhf said.